# What would happen to an object if one was to drop it in intergalactic space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, universe

This might be a dumb question but i was confused as to what would happen if one was to somehow drop an object in intergalactic space. For example when something is dropped on earth it falls to the ground due to the gravity, but if we was to drop an object in intergalactic space where no large object is near, what would happen to said object? would it just float in the direction of Largest object near by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if we was to drop an object in intergalactic space where no large
>   object is near, what would happen to said object? would it just float
>   in the direction of Largest object near by?

The short answer is it might "float" (not accelerate) for a while, but probably not for long.

The Newtonian force of gravity has an infinite range. There is nowhere in space not under the influence of gravity, no matter how far from gravitating bodies. While the net gravitational force may be very small at a particular point in space, and even zero at times, gravitating bodies are constantly on the move.  So net gravitational force at a particular point in space relative to other bodies is constantly changing.

> if it would be placed where the net gravitational force was 0 and it
>   was placed by someone stationary what would happen? would it just be
>   still?

You need to understand that nothing in the universe is "still". Even if not accelerating, everything is in motion relative to something else. No net force does not mean something is still. It only means it is not accelerating. Your computer on your desk appears to be still to you. But relative to someone driving at constant velocity and looking at your computer through your window, your computer and you, and your house for that matter, are  moving relative to them.

Since everything is moving relative to other things, the distance between things is constantly changing. The gravitational forces, which depend on the separation of things, also changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if it would be placed where the net gravitational force was $0$ and it was placed by someone stationary what would happen? would it just be still?

Comment: @Gibberish The object & the stationary person would be gravitationally attracted towards each other, but their accelerations would be rather small.

Comment: @Gibberish See update to my answer in response to your follow up comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: @BobD Thanks for the detailed answer given.